# Conditional auth_basic_user_file depending on the request path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, nginx

I would like to authorize users depending on the requested path. For example, only `user1` and `user2` should have access to `/projects/1`.

My `/etc/nginx/.htpasswd` looks like this:

```
user1:$hashed_psswd1
user2:$hashed_psswd2
user3:$hashed_psswd3
...
```

Here's the `location` block in nginx config:

```
location ~ /projects(/.*) {
    auth_basic "Please provide credentials";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    include /var/www/html/myapp.com/config/nginx/git-http-backend.conf;
}
```

And the rails action:

```
def git
  redirect_to "#{Rails.configuration.x.domain}/projects/#{@project.id}"
end
```

The authentication seems to work:

```
$ git clone http://localhost:3000/projects/1
Cloning into '1'...
Username for 'http://localhost:3001': user1  
Password for 'http://deploy@localhost:3001': 
remote: Enumerating objects: 94, done.
# ... it successfully clones the git repo...
```

The problem is that `user3` is able to clone project `1`, but he shouldn't be able to clone such project.

So how could I authorize users in nginx + rails depending on the requested path?

Comment: Where do you want to authorize users? If you want to do it at the backend, check and process the [`Authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header. If you want to do it with the nginx, use several password files. And what is the matter to use regex location? Why do not use prefix `location /projects/ { ... }`?

Comment: Hi @Ivan. I tried to use project-specific password files with `location ~ /projects(/.*) { set $file /projects$1/.htpasswd; auth_basic_user_file $file; }` but discovered that [auth_basic_user_file doesn't allow a variable as argument](https://serverfault.com/questions/485911). The goal is to authorize with login + password. If it can't be done with nginx, i could write a bash or ruby CGI script and have rails point to it to authorize users.

Comment: But nginx documentation on [`auth_basic_user_file`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html#auth_basic_user_file) directive explicitly states that the filename can contain variables (otherwise I wouldn't suggest it). The answer you are referring on is 8 years old. What nginx version are you using?

Comment: I'm using nginx 1.20.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a config I've just tested with OpenResty 1.17.8.2 (based on nginx 1.17.8 core) and can confirm that it is workable:

```
map $uri $realm {
    ~^/projects/    "Protected projects";
    ~^/images/      "Protected images";
    default         off;
}
map $uri $authfile {
    ~^/projects/    /path/to/.htpasswd_projects;
    ~^/images/      /path/to/.htpasswd_images;
}
server {
    ...
    auth_basic $realm;
    auth_basic_user_file $authfile;
    ...
}
```

`.htpasswd_projects` and `.htpasswd_images` files contains each own user/password list. With the above config every URI started with `/projects/` prefix is protected with basic authorization and available only for users listed in the `htpasswd_projects` file, every URI started with `/images/` is protected with basic authorization and available only for users listed in the `htpasswd_images` file, and rest of the URIs are available without authorization for everyone.

**Update**

Here is another example, using dynamically generated `.htpasswd` path depending on the requested URI:

```
location ~ ^/projects/(?<project_id>[^/]+) {
    if (!-f /var/www/projects/$project_id/.htpasswd) {
        # '.htpasswd' file for the requested project does not exists
        # assuming wrong project ID is given, returning HTTP 404 Not found
        return 404;
    }
    auth_basic "Please provide credentials for project $1";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/projects/$project_id/.htpasswd;
    ...
}
```

This one would work with the following `.htpasswd` files tree:

```
/var/www/projects
         ├── 1
         │   └── .htpasswd
         ├── 2
         │   └── .htpasswd
         ...
```

You can place this `projects` directory wherever you want, it isn't dependent on web server root.